# Unity Input detected multiple times in a press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a source `MonoBehavior` script with these methods:

```
private void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
        HandleInput();
    }
}

private void HandleInput () {
    Ray inputRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(inputRay, out hit)) {
        var position = transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);
        Coordinates coords = Coordinates.FromPosition(position);
        HexCell cell = null;        
        if (!cells.TryGetValue(coords, out cell)) {
            var err = string.Format("{0} is an invalid position and coordinates are improperly calculated: {1}", position, coords);
            print(err);

            throw new System.ArgumentException(err);
        }

        print(string.Format("[{0}] cell: [{1}] {2}", DateTime.Now, cell.id, cell.coordinates));
        OnCellTouched(cell);
    }
}
```

The mesh is transparent and I get the hexagon (cell) as expected. In the editor, I get a single message output when I click on a cell:

```
[05.31.2017.14.15.14.2836] cell: [0] [x=0;y=0;z=0]  
[05.31.2017.14.15.15.7359] cell: [197] [x=12;y=-22;z=10]
```

However, when I build and run the application: single-click on any cell, the following is logged 4 - 6 times per click:

```
[05.31.2017.14.57.50.1588] cell: [0] [x=0;y=0;z=0]
[05.31.2017.14.57.50.1695] cell: [0] [x=0;y=0;z=0]
[05.31.2017.14.57.50.1861] cell: [0] [x=0;y=0;z=0]
[05.31.2017.14.57.50.2028] cell: [0] [x=0;y=0;z=0]
[05.31.2017.14.57.50.2195] cell: [0] [x=0;y=0;z=0]
[05.31.2017.14.57.52.6195] cell: [197] [x=12;y=-22;z=10]
[05.31.2017.14.57.52.6360] cell: [197] [x=12;y=-22;z=10]
[05.31.2017.14.57.52.6530] cell: [197] [x=12;y=-22;z=10]
[05.31.2017.14.57.52.6691] cell: [197] [x=12;y=-22;z=10]
[05.31.2017.14.57.52.6857] cell: [197] [x=12;y=-22;z=10]
```

Is it possible that a single click is propagated multiple times by the Unity engine that the editor is ignoring? Since each log entry has a different time stamp (milliseconds), the range difference being 157-170ms.

Is there a "best practice" in the Unity paradigm? Should the handler be async? Should the handler ignore subsequent calls within a certain window?

It seems like this would cause problems when I want to use a single click as a toggle on a hexagon tile.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a problem almost all new Unity programmers go through.

- [`Input.GetMouseButton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButton.html) is `true` every frame when the mouse
  Button is held down until released. Again, it will be `true` **every
  frame** until released.
- [`Input.GetMouseButtonDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) is `true` just **once** when the
  mouse button held down. It will **not** be `true` again until mouse is
  released and pressed again.

In your case, it looks like you need [`Input.GetMouseButtonDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html)  which will only be true once and can only be true again when released and pressed again.

The-same thing applies to `GetKey`, `GetKeyDown` and `GetKeyUp`.

**Note**:

If you use [`Input.GetMouseButtonDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetMouseButtonDown.html) but it is still being called multiple times then make sure that your script is not attached to another or multiple GameObjects.

[image]

Comment: Lifesaver ...I've got to get this journey documented so I can correct about a dozen tutorials.

Comment: As I am finding out ... especially this nonsense regarding planes, 10:1 unit ratio and perpendicular to camera. Drove me nuts until I figured that out.

Comment: Wait until you run into *Null Exception* error just because of *Script Execution problem* in Unity. It's a rare problem but I have seen it a lot here. It's hard to even fix unless you understand that problem.

Comment: As a note, if you are using Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) or Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) and it is still triggering multiple times then make sure your script is only in the scene 1 time.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had placed the Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) inside FixedUpdate. Because of this, Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) returns true multiple times in a single mouse click. Replace FixedUpdate with Update, and it will work.