# Unity3d GetMouseButtonDown(0) trigger twice on one click

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a very simple unity3d monoBehavior and attach it to a cube.

The script is as follow:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("down");
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Debug.Log("up");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I swipe my mouse on the screen, the log was weird.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdH6l.png)

As in the snapshot, when I swipe the third time, the `GetMouseButtonUp(0)` generate three log, one `down` and two `up`s.

So when `GetMouseButtonUp(0)` triggered, if there's something I was lost?

I find something like this, but the situation is not the same.

[Unity Input detected multiple times in a press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295502/unity-input-detected-multiple-times-in-a-press)

In fact, there is a more complicated script, I found this issue, so write the minimal script as above, and didn't find the answer.

====== @2023-03-19

I used the follow code pattern to avoid this problem for temprory.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private mSwipping = false;
    void Update()
    {
        if (!mSwipping && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            mSwipping = true;
            Debug.Log("down");
        }
        if (mSwipping && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            mSwipping = false;
            Debug.Log("up");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As in the snapshot, when I swipe the third time, the mouse button up action generate three log, one down and two ups.

Comment: Does swipe mean move?

Comment: @shingo yes shingo, I mean put my finger on screen, and then move, and then up my finger

Comment: Maybe your third click was taken as a multitap, you can log `Input.touchCount` to make sure.

Comment: Yes Yes, this is a possibility. But I tried this, the touchCount always 1.